# Show and Hide Fragments on Button Click

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm developing an application which consists of `Fragment`s, When I click on the button it should show and hide. By default I have set fragments as visibility gone, even though this is also not working for me:

```
FragmentTransaction  mFragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
mMenuFragment = new MenuFragment();
mFragmentTransaction.add(R.id.frmMenuBar, mMenuFragment); 
mFragmentTransaction.hide(mMenuFragment);
mFragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
mFragmentTransaction.commit();
```

The code below I kept on button click.

```
@Override
protected void onMenuButtonClick(View Button) {
super.onMenuButtonClick(Button);
System.out.println("Botton Clciked");

if (Button.isClickable()) {
    FragmentTransaction menuTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    menuTransaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
    menuTransaction.show(mMenuFragment);
    menuTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    menuTransaction.commit();
} else {
    FragmentTransaction menuShowTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    menuShowTransaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
    menuShowTransaction.hide(mMenuFragment);
    menuShowTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    menuShowTransaction.commit();
}
}
```

Please can any one help me.

Comment: When i click on button fragments is not hiding and showing